# Encoding Problem

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to export the data from a DaraGrid into an Excel file. Having these data in a french language
Here you are my method:

```
public static void ExportGridView( DataGrid dataGrid, string fileName)
    {
        HttpResponse m_Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        m_Response.Clear();
        m_Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
        m_Response.Charset = "";           
        m_Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; //"application/vnd.xls";
        m_Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF32;
        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        m_Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        m_Response.End();

}
```

Otherwise the output isn't in a the good French format

Ex )

Engagé => engagÃ©

Société => SociÃ©tÃ©

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `ISO-8859-1`:

```
public static void ExportGridView(DataGrid dataGrid, string fileName)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    var isoEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    response.Charset = isoEncoding.WebName;
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.ContentEncoding = isoEncoding;
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer))
    {
        dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        response.Write(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
    }
    response.End();
}
```

Another alternative and probably better is to generate an entire HTML page and specify the UTF8 encoding which IMHO is better:

```
public static void ExportGridView(DataGrid dataGrid, string fileName)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer))
    {
        dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        string html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><title>Test</title><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>{0}</body></html>";
        response.Write(string.Format(html, writer.GetStringBuilder()));
    }
    response.End();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Dick, Darin and for all the people who answered. 
Your second solution Darin is perfect, however the ISO-8859-1 didn't solve the problem. It was the UTF8

Comment: The second approach worked for me, first one (without the full HTML syntax) didn't. Using MS Office Professional Plus 2013 to open saved file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content encoding to UTF8 should guarantee that special symbols in the Excel file will be interpreted properly. Of course, you need to make sure you have French fonts on the client machine installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that he/she is using utf32 for a reason. I'd be tempted to strike that line completely and see what happens. utf8 would work if it was going FROM Excel to DataGrid I think you are right there, but it's the other way around. That line might not even be a problem.

I'm more suspicious of those "StringWriter" objects. I'm not familiar with those. If you ARE using html to move things around, browsers are not supposed to be able to recognize utf32, and they instead treat it like utf16, which might be your problem.